# What this cast and assignment is all about?

Tags: pthreads, preprocessor, mutex

I am reading Richard Stevens' Advance Programming in unix environment.
There is a code in thread synchronization category (chapter - 11).
This is code showing is showing how to avoid race conditions for many shared structure of same type.
This code is showing two mutex for synch.- one for a list `fh` (a list which keep track of all the foo structures) & `f_next` field and another for the structure `foo`
*The code is:*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NHASH 29
#define HASH(fp) (((unsigned long)fp)%NHASH)

struct foo *fh[NHASH];

pthread_mutex_t hashlock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

struct foo {
  int             f_count;
  pthread_mutex_t f_lock;
  struct foo     *f_next; /* protected by hashlock */
  int             f_id;
  /* ... more stuff here ... */
};

struct foo * foo_alloc(void) /* allocate the object */
{
  struct foo  *fp;
  int         idx;

  if ((fp = malloc(sizeof(struct foo))) != NULL) {
      fp->f_count = 1;
      if (pthread_mutex_init(&fp->f_lock, NULL) != 0) {
          free(fp);
          return(NULL);
      }
      idx = HASH(fp);
      pthread_mutex_lock(&hashlock);
      ///////////////////// HERE -----------------
      fp->f_next = fh[idx];
      fh[idx] = fp->f_next;
      //////////////////// UPTO HERE -------------
      pthread_mutex_lock(&fp->f_lock);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&hashlock);
      /* ... continue initialization ... */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&fp->f_lock);
  }
  return(fp);
}

void foo_hold(struct foo *fp) /* add a reference to the object */
.......
```

**The doubt is**
**1)** What is `HASH(fp)` pre-processor doing?
I know that it is typecasting what is `fp` store and then taking its modulo. But, in the function `foo_alloc` we are just passing the address of newly allocated foo structure.
Why we are doing this I know that this will give me a integer between 0 and 28 - to store in array `fh`. But why are we taking modulo of an address. Why there is so much randomization?

**2)** Suppose i accept that, now after this what these two lines are doing (also highlighted in the code) :

```
fp->f_next = fh[idx];
fh[idx] = fp->f_next;
```

I hope initially `fh[idx]` has any garbage value which i assigned to the `f_next` field of foo and in the next line what is happening , again the same assignment but in opposite order.

Answer (score 0):

`struct foo *fh[NHASH]` is a hash table, and use the `HASH` macro as the hash function.

1) `HASH(fp)` calculates the index to decide where the in the `fh` to store `fp`, and it uses the address of the `fp` and uses the address as key to calculate the index.  We can easily typecast the address to the long type.

2) Use the  linked list to avoid the hash collisions called separate chaining,  and I think the following cod is right, and you can check it in the book :

```
fp->f_next = fh[idx];
fh[idx] = fp;
```

insert the fp element to the header of the linked list `fh[idx]`, and the initial value of the `fh[idx]` is null.